# Alpha Numeric values xcannot be retrieved in PHP

Tags: php

I am currently working on this project. Data can be retrieved from database with this code, if certificateNumber is numeric, but it does not search person if certificateNumber field has alphanumeric data.

Where am I wrong with this?

```
<?php
$flag = 0;
$reg=$_REQUEST["cerf"];
echo ($reg);
$con = mysqli_connect('localhost','neoncom_db','12345','neoncom_std');
$qur = 'select * from student where  certificateNumber = '.$reg;
$check = mysqli_query($con,$qur);
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($check))
 {
  if($reg==$row["certificateNumber"])
  {
    $flag++;
    $first = $row["first"];
    $last=$row["last"];
    $num = $row["certificateNumber"];
    $name = $first ." ".$last;
    $course = $row["course"];
    $date = $row["signupDate"];
    echo($row["certificateNumber"]);
    echo($row["first"]);
    echo($row["last"]);
    }
    }

if(count==0)
{
echo("NOT FOUND");
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to encapsulate `$reg` in quotes. So your query string `$qur` should be like this:

```
$qur = "select * from student where  certificateNumber = '" . $reg . "'";
```

---

**Sidenote:** Learn about [**prepared statement**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) because right now your query is susceptible to SQL injection attack. Also see [**how you can prevent SQL injection in PHP**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php).